# Guidewire APD giving Regex pattern error while trying to add schedule items under schedule coverage

Tags: guidewire

I am working on GUidewire APD app to add schedule coverages and schedule items under that. I have added Schedule coverage successfully but while adding items by giving Label , shortName and Type as 'Involved Party',  I am getting 'The value dies not match the regex pattern' error.
Please let me know anyone faced this issue and have any solution?

I tried giving the shortName as 'NmdPm'. And couple of different options. Nothing is working

Comment: There is probably a naming convention that Guidewire is enforcing via a regular expression. I'll do a quick search of the APD documentation and give you a link to it. A Guidewire partner or community account would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following documentation links. Keep in mind that you must have a Guidewire login to access.

https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/apd/innsbruck/create/topics/r_field-name-conventions.html?hl=conventions,naming,names,name

https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/apd/innsbruck/create/topics/c_xmind-labels.html?hl=conventions,naming,names,name

https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/apd/innsbruck/create/topics/c_add-product-labels.html

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you for reply. Yes We are following the naming convention mentioned in gw doc. Ours is a multiline product in APD. We are able to add Schedule Condition and Schedule items under one of the line and in the other line we face this error though we followed the same pattern as used in other line.

Comment: I think the multiline is your issue.  Note the following from the APD App documentation:  "You cannot make product model changes to a product line within a multi-line product; you must make the changes in the mono-line product."

Comment: Yes we are making changes on moniline and attaching it to multiline product

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear.  Please open a ticket with GW support to report the issue and attach the exported line from the APD app to get assistance.  It sounds like there's an issue of some kind and we can't really assist in that area here.  Good luck!